# C# ComboBox in DropDownList style, how do I set the text?

Tags: c#, .net, combobox

I want to use a ComboBox with the DropDownList style (the one that makes it look like a button so you can't enter a value) to insert a value into a text box. I want the combobox to have a text label called 'Wildcards' and as I select a wildcard from the list the selected value is inserted in to a text box and the combobox text remains 'Wildcard'. My first problem is I can't seem to set a text value when the combobox is in DropDownList style. Using the properties pallet doesn't work the text value is simply cleared when you click off, adding comboBox.Text = "Wildcards"; to form_load doesn't work either. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The code you specify:

```
comboBox.Text = "Wildcards";
```

...should work. The only reason it would not is that the text you specify is not an item within the comboBox's item list. When using the DropDownList style, you can only set Text to values that actually appear in the list.

If it is the case that you are trying to set the text to Wildcards and that item does not appear in the list, and an alternative solution is not acceptable, you may have to be a bit dirty with the code and add an item temporarily that is removed when the drop-down list is expanded.

For example, if you have a form containing a combobox named "comboBox1" with some items and a button named "button1" you could do something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!comboBox1.Items.Contains("Wildcards"))
    {
        comboBox1.Items.Add("Wildcards");
    }

    comboBox1.Text = "Wildcards";
}

private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.Items.Contains("Wildcards"))
        comboBox1.Items.Remove("Wildcards");
}
```

That's pretty quick and dirty but by capturing the DropDownClosed event too you could clean it up a bit, adding the "Wildcards" item back as needed.

Comment: Thanks for that, I learnt a lot of my C# from the blackwasp web site and I still refer to it. Thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, setting the "Text" property within the form designer is not enough--it must be set in the code behind in my case. Attempting to set it from the form properties window would just wipe the "Text" property clean after clicking off of it.

Comment: Instead of  "Wildcards",  you could use "! Wildcards !". The exclamation point should force it to be the first item in a sorted list (of text anyway), and it looks more like a title for your list (I like to use "! Select Item !" because it informs the OP to make a selection.

Answer (score 6):

You can select one of items on formload or in form constructor:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

or

```
private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    comboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
}
```

Comment: And also you can use comboBox.SelectedIndex = -1; to clean comboBox.Text.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue = "Wildcards";
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be a possible solution:

```
comboBox1.SelectedValue = comboBox1.Items.FindByText("Wildcards").Value;
```